# How to do work with odd number of columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Usually we can't make `<div>` center align while working with odd columns. Here is my problem.

This is developed using Bootstrap. I want all inner divs to be in the center. So, when the page is viewed on other devices everything is center-aligned. When viewed at `md` screen width there is a little space on right side.

I want three columns at `md` and `lg` widths, two columns at `sm` widths, and one column at `xs` width. On all viewports, it should be center-aligned.

Here is my markup:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-centered">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-iii/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/III-01-300x240.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream III</h4>
</div>

<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-iv-sp-1/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/V2-1-300x240.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream V2</h4>
</div>




<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-iv-sp-1/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/FLEET_SP1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream SP1</h4>
</div>

<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't add margin/padding to the Bootstrap grid classes, you'll break the grid. For example `.fleet_bor` adds a margin, which makes the 3rd image occur not in the 3rd column but on a new line. As a tip I would suggest you to first create the layout using only Bootstrap's grid classes and afterwards start adding the content by adding additional `<div>`'s inside the grid.

Comment: @NiMa when i try to do the thing it make my layout worst you can check by doing inspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a best solution regarding this, i have this issue due to odd number of columns so i just added a span column on left and right side and the working columns in middle, that it solved my problem!, here is code what i did.

```html
<div class="entry-content">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs"></div>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-11 col-xs-12 moile_fix_">
<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-iii/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/III-01-300x240.jpg">
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream III</h4>
</div>

<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4  col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12  col-xs-offset-0">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-iv-sp-1/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/V2-1-300x240.jpg">
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream V2</h4>
</div>

<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-iv-sp-1/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/FLEET_SP1.jpg">
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream SP1</h4>
</div>

<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4  col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12  col-xs-offset-0">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-g550/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/G5500-1-300x244.jpg">
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream G550</h4>
</div>

<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-v1/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/V1-1-300x240.jpg">
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream V1</h4>
</div>

<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4  col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12  col-xs-offset-0">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-iv-sp-2/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/FLEET_SP2.jpg">
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream SP2</h4>
</div>

<div class="fleet_bor col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <a href="http://someurl.com/gulfstream-iv-sp-3/">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://someurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/FLEET-SP3.jpg">
    </a>
    <h4>Gulfstream SP3</h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in outer div and offset the col.

It is not perfect, but it works. You'll need to make the transition fluid as well, but it should help you get everything centered-ish

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you please give me some example of above.

Comment: @Sohail Did you click the link I provided? Everything you need is in the Bootstrap Docs